# How can you search for a char in a string in bash?

Tags: bash, bash4

If I have a string `var="root/Desktop"`, how can I determine whether `var` var contains a `'/'` character?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bash can match against regular expressions with `=~`, try:

```
[[ $var =~ "/" ]] && echo "contains a slash"
```

Comment: +1 - Yours is better than using grep. But I think using an external program has its advantages.

Answer (score 4):

The following would work

```
[[ "$var" = */* ]]
```

Answer (score 3):

The portable solution that works in *any* Bourne-heritage shell and needs no expensive forks or pipes:

```
 case $var in
   (*/*)   printf 'Has a slash.\n';;
   (*)     printf 'No slash.\n';;
 esac
```

Answer (score 2):

`echo "${var1}" | grep '/'` should work.

Comment: Don't forget to quote `"${var1}"`, you never know.